# No provider for NavController(in service)

Tags: ionic2

Injecting NavController in constructor of service fails with no provider error. Can someone please provide a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you provide the full error message, and at least the portion of your code that receives it?

Answer (score 2):

`NavController` is **NOT** meant to be injected into the Service class because this is not their intended purpose. The service shouldn't be responsible for displaying alerts/loading/ or any component that needs to be activated by nav. A service should just be for getting and returning data. Anything else should be done within the component.

Following is the guideline with services:

> It's bad practice to change a view from a service (broken MVC).
>   However, you could send events from services to the main controller,
>   and the controller can use NavController (best way), or you could send
>   NavController to your service like an attribute (not bad way...). Or
>   you may need to create a component instead of using the service.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `NavController` in service by normal way. You should do like that:

```
import {  App} from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(private app: App){
}
gotoPage(page: any){
    this.app.getRootNav().push(page);
}
```

Comment: This should work but @Debo if you really need to navigate to another page from a service, then **the architecture design of your app is wrong**. You should instead return some results from the service and navigate from the page that's calling the service in the first place. But +1 since, again, this should work.